# Delete the 'grammer' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

While looking for a tag I found that there is a [grammer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammer) tag.  This is clearly a mis-spelling of the [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag.

[grammer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammer) has been synonymized with [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar).

Surely a mis-spelt tag should be deleted, not synonymized.  Can we please delete [grammer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammer).

I believe that leaving an incorrect tag in the system doesn't help our users improve their English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym is helpful.  If anyone spells it wrong (and it's a fairly common mistake), it's automatically replaced with the correct spelling.  What's more, this prevents them from creating a [grammer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammer) tag.  This is a good thing.

We shouldn't delete this synonym.

Comment: Point taken, perhaps then a tag wiki on 'grammer'

Comment: Is it possible to have a tag wiki on a synonym?  I'm not sure.  In any case, it may be best to think of it as an alias rather than a synonym, despite the name.  It exists to save ELLers some effort, not to legitimize a non-standard spelling.

Comment: It appears that you can't put a tag wiki on a synonym.

Comment: The auto-completion should take care of this common misspelling. When you type on g-r-a-m, it will show you the correct tag. This isn't really a use case for tag synonyms.

Comment: @robert Would this be a case, then, where if we remove the synonym and see that the "grammer" tag is still being used, "grammer" could be blacklisted to avoid the problem?

Comment: @WendiKidd If this were *truly* a recurring problem, blacklisting might be warranted. But the higher-reputation requirements to create a new tag should take care of that happening... and when you graduate, the reputation requirements will be higher still.