# Should we delete "Word tags"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

## Single word tags

I don't think we need a tag for individual English words. I see eight right now.

[as](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/as)[so](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/so)[mean](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mean)[until](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/until)[too](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/too)[who](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/who)[such](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/such)[neither](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neither) (If you find any others, feel free to add them to this list.)

I think [as](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/as) *might* be useful, since there are 53 questions tagged with it, but I'm not sure any of the others are. (all of them have 5 or less tags)

Personally, I think we should delete all of them. What do you think we should do with these type of tags?

Comment: [tag:mean] isn't being used as a word tag. It's just being used by confused users as a synonym of [tag:meaning].

Answer (score 4):

## Delete most of these tags.

These kind of tags are generally not constructive, and have few tags. However, *some* of them are very useful and already get used (more specifically, [as](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/as) has 53 tags). There is no need to delete these tags.

Comment: Certain words (particularly two letter ones) are difficult to construct a search for in English, and I think the tags help filter the results so I vote we keep some of them.

Answer (score 0):

## We should delete these tags.

There is no need or reason to have a tag for individual English Words. If someone has a question about a word, there is definitely a more appropriate tag that they can add than the word itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited away [too](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/too) and [neither](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neither) on [the only question](//ell.stackexchange.com/q/46527/5289) that used them.

Answer (score -1):

## Leave them as-is.

If people want to give a single word tag, we should let them. It doesn't harm the quality of their question, and it could make it easier for someone to find. If there is a question with *only* a single-word tag, we can always add additional tags that are appropriate to the question.